# print() statement not printing to console in flutter iOS app within Android Studio

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter

The print() statement is not printing any data within Android Studio's console in Flutter iOS version, but same code works fine for flutter android version.

Here is the flutter Doctor summary:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.10.7-pre.109, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103, locale en-IN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: it should be print(), with lower case p

Comment: that is a typo, I'm facing the issue with print() statement only. It is not working when in run the flutter app in iOS.

Comment: try `po()` in console

Comment: Please add some code to your question

Comment: @FernandoRocha, Not to any specific piece of code, even for a simple print('Hello!') statement within the main function of the sample flutter app has this issue in physical iOS devices.

Comment: did you check and see if it prints at xcode console? since its the iOS version

Comment: Same issue here - output is logged correctly in Xcode.

Comment: This is a known issue with the current version of flutter because of the way that iOS 13.0 works on apple devices. You're options are to use a simulator and not a physical device, or move over to the beta channel.

Comment: @R.Duggan have you got a link to further information or discussion about the problem with iOS 13?

Comment: @MattR https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41133

Answer (score 41):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was to add

```
import 'dart:developer';
```

to the top of my file, and then use

```
log('your message here');
```

instead of print.

Comment: we can only use logs with Strings.. but I want to log double any solution?

Comment: Interesting find here. Should these statements be commented in production build or they are automatically ignored?

Comment: @ChiragChopra use interpolation like this `log("$my_double_var")`

Answer (score 12):

had same issue... embarrassing said that I had my debug console filtered without realize it .. after I remove the filter text I could see all my print() and log()

Comment: that was me lol

Comment: @Claudio Moscoso  Can you explain remove 'filter text'  where?  Tnx

Comment: @Pointer when you search a text i.e (mac) cmd + shift + f. that would be the "filter text" that a mean.

Answer (score 10):

you should try

```
debugPrint("")
```

to print in the console

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue.

As a workaround:

Select 'more actions' in the console, 'Open observatory' and the 'see debug' link. Then you can see the outputs of the print statements.

Comment: It is weird that it is happening after I updated it today. Your workaround helps, but I can't use vscode

Answer (score 3):

We stumbled upon it today and apparently the first line of some loggings doesn't appear. So if you start with a `\n` before your loggings it should work.

```swift
os_log("\n  We're using this")
```

Comment: it worked for me `flutter 2.0.2`, flutter ios has very strange bugs like these lol

Answer (score 1):

In my case this happened because I changed the display name in Xcode from Runner to something else. Everything was working fine, but there was no log output.

Answer (score 0):

On *pubspec.yaml* change:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
```

TO

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"
```

Or high!

To more information visit [Dart Diagnostic](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#sdk_version_set_literal)

Answer (score 0):

**For**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on macOS 12.2 21D49 darwin-x64, locale en-NG)
    • Flutter version 2.10.3 at /Users/theodore_mca/softwares_and_sdks/flutter2
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7e9793dee1 (6 days ago), 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
    • Engine revision bd539267b4
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2
```

**Or Later**

```
import 'dart:developer';

log("Theodore");
```

**For regular strings**

```
import 'dart:developer';

  final Map<String, dynamic> value = {"email2":'_emailController.text',};
  value.addAll({
              "email":'_emailController.text',
               "username":'_usernameController.text'});
  
  log(value.toString());
```

**For complex Data Type**