# Why does flutter API response body not print in console?

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart, openweathermap

I am trying to send an API request using [dart http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http/versions/0.13.3). I am new to developing in flutter (but I have coded extensively in java however). I was wondering why the response body would not print in the console. I added the dependency in the pubscpec.yaml and imported in the top of the page. There is no issue with the importing as I get no error when running (no words having any red lines and correctly autocompletes)
Here is the code to the function used to send the request

```
void getData() async {
    var url = Uri.parse("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=110a603f26f6f7e2ade19f00669dc8fa");
    var response = await http.get(url);
    print('Response body: ${response.body}');
  }
```

**Note: the API key is the default developer key provided by openweathermap**
When I run, I get no error, just a clean console, nothing is printed under the run tab
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print() statement not printing to console in flutter iOS app within Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58201578/print-statement-not-printing-to-console-in-flutter-ios-app-within-android-stud)

Comment: no, because in the same project, I already print something succesfully

Comment: Excessive `print` messages might be discarded (which is why you should use [`debugPrint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/debugPrint.html) instead).  Even with `debugPrint`, very long messages might get truncated by the OS.

Comment: I tried running your code but the print worked just fine. Could you provide more information like the context in which the method is being called?

Comment: Seems like there is an issue with the Android Manifest, I’ve added the internet permission but the Android Manifest itself is full of erors. Every time I create a new flutter project, or even import one from github, it used to work fine, no errors in the android manifest, now it is full of errors and ”cannot resolve any symbols”

Comment: The project runs anyway however, but I think any permissions do not work. Please help me with this issue, I have been unable to create any flutter apps so far. I have already asked this question before but someone told me that it works fine anyway, I was skeptical however: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68369197/android-manifest-full-of-errors-after-migration-from-pre-1-12-flutter

Comment: Is it possible to upload your working project to guthub to allow me to run the exact same code and see if this is an error with android studio

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can open flutter dev tool and under the network tab check whether you are getting response or not,
may be that await never finished and execution never reached the print statement,
so it doesn't get printed

Answer (score 1):

make sure you called getData in InitState....
i was facing same issue it worked for me :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33085436)